# Strange bug in Objective-C with a basic float computation

Tags: objective-c

There is the chance that I am stupid right now, but check this. I have a float:

```
float wordTime=46.81; // I get it after some calculations
```

Then I am logging this:

```
NSLog(@"1:%f", wordTime);
NSLog(@"2:%f", (3/2)*wordTime);
NSLog(@"3:%f", (5/2)*wordTime);
NSLog(@"4:%f", (7/2)*wordTime);
```

I get this: (which has a problem with log number 2)

```
 46.81
 46.81 // weird
 93.8
140.7
```

Then I have changed the `3/2` to `1.5` and I got 46, 70, 93, and 140. What am I missing here?

Comment: `3/2` is an integer division.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`3/2` is interpreted as `(int)3/2` and therefore evaluates to `1`. You can write out the types explicitly as `3.0f/2.0f` instead, which should give the result you expect (just as explicitly casting the whole expression to `float`).

Comment: @Rant You're not stupid. You just haven't read fully that C tutorial :) Do that. (General advice: try to master C before touching Obejctive-C/OS X/iOS programming.)

Comment: Everyone was bitten by this once. At least once, that is :)

Comment: thanks a lot both. this is the second time it happens to me .

Comment: @Rant If you were stupid you probably wouldn't have noticed that your code was incorrectly dividing! (Well, it was dividing correctly from a C standard but you know what I mean)

Comment: oh ! you are so supported :) thanks ! i will accept this answer when it let me .

Answer (score 4):

Cast one of the operands so the other operand will be promoted to float and you'll have a float division instead of an integer division:

```
NSLog(@"2:%f",(3.0/2)*wordTime  );
```